# Compare Date using calculated date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

So uhm,

I have this table with a calculated expiration date where course completion + 1 year = expiration date.

Now I want to just get the records of users who are already expired. Meaning I will compare the expiration date from today.

```
SELECT 
    employee.data AS 'Employee No.',
CONCAT(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) AS 'Full Name',
CONCAT('<a target="_new" href="%%WWWROOT%%/user/profile.php?id=',u.id,'">', u.username,'</a>') AS 'User Name',
    org.data AS 'Organisation',
c.fullname AS 'Course',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timeenrolled),'%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Enrollment Date',
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),'%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Completion Date',
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),INTERVAL 1 YEAR), '%m/%d/%Y') AS 'Expiration Date' 

FROM prefix_course_completions p
JOIN prefix_course c ON p.course = c.id
JOIN prefix_user u ON p.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT d.userid, d.data
     FROM prefix_user_info_data d
     JOIN prefix_user_info_field f ON f.id = d.fieldid AND f.shortname = 'employeeid'
) employee ON employee.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT d.userid, d.data
     FROM prefix_user_info_data d
     JOIN prefix_user_info_field f ON f.id = d.fieldid AND f.shortname = 'Organisation'
) org ON org.userid = u.id

WHERE DATE((FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) < CURDATE()

%%FILTER_COURSES:Course%%
%%FILTER_USERS:org.data%%
%%FILTER_SEARCHTEXT:employee.data:~%%

ORDER BY employee.data
```

It's always giving me error whenever i try to use this

```
WHERE DATE((FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) < CURDATE()
```

Comment: Use `-` instead of `,` like `WHERE DATE((FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted,[FORMAT]) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) < CURDATE()`

Comment: I don't have a table for the expiration day in my database that's why I am just calculating it.........

Comment: @1000111 I tried that but it gives me Query failed error 

`WHERE DATE((FROM_UNIXTIME(p.timecompleted)-INTERVAL 1 YEAR) < CURDATE()`

Comment: The signature of `FROM_UNIXTIME` function is `FROM_ UNIXTIME (unix_timestamp, [format ])`. You need to provide the format in the second argument.

Comment: What's the datatype of `p. timecompleted`?